# Python return возвращает некорректные данные

Tags: python

Функция принимает нижнюю и верхнюю границы диапазона чисел. В результате работы функция должна вернуть список четных чисел в последовательности. Также код должен корректно отрабатывать, если начальное число(аргумент) больше конечного.

Написал код, но функция возвращает пустой список. В чем может быть проблeма?

```
def paired_numbers(start, end):
    list_of_paired = []
    if start < end:
        temp = start
        start = end
        end = temp

        for i in range(start, end):
            if i % 2 == 0:
                list_of_paired.append(i)
        return (list_of_paired)
start = int(input("Введите нижнюю границу: "))
end = int(input("Введите верхнюю границу: "))
print(paired_numbers(start, end))
print("=" * 100)
```

Comment: Что такое "сортировка парных чисел"?? По факту вы делаете фильтрацию, оставляя только чётные числа из диапазона.

Comment: Код должен быть текстом, а не скриншотом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. У Вас `return` не на том уровне... Удалите один tab, и скобки в return не нужны.
2. Условие start < end не имеет смысла.

Как-то так в итоге должно выглядеть. Возьмите на заметку способ для "поменять местами start и end" без темповой переменной

```
def paired_numbers(start, end):
    if start > end:
        start, end = end, start
    output_list = []
    for each in range(start, end):
        if each % 2 == 0:
            output_list.append(each)
    return (output_list)
print(paired_numbers(99, -99))
```

Comment: Так то оно так, но у автора условие If start < end. И зачем тут enumerate?

Comment: И попробуйте ввести чётное число в качестве большего числа.

Comment: и зачем вообще давать ответы на вопросы, нарушающие рекомендации сайта?

Comment: @Никомах подправил, спасибо.